# NODE-OPTION works as prefix in scripts on package.json but doesnt as a `˜/.zshrc variable`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, openssl, package.json

I have an issue that I want to solve, but I cannot do it works.

I had to implement the solution `NODE-OPTION=--openssl-legacy-provider` to solve an error between my projects and OpenSSL.

If I put a solution as a prefix in scripts section on package.json, it works very well.

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
   "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

Now if I use this variable as NODE_OPTION as export in ~/.zshrc I got this error:

```
--openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

Any idea?

I would like to find an alternative that I can use the flag `--openssl-legacy-provider` and I dont have to modify the package.json because I dont want to bother my co-workers.

Thanks!